# Is it possible to address whole table by ID?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating database in which I will have devices list in first table and features in second table. I know that I can initialize relation between those tables in that way:

```
+----------------+                 +----------------------+
|     device     |                 |   features           |
+----------------+                 +----------------------+
|   ID           |--------+        |ID                    |
|   dName        |        +--------|dID                   |
+----------------+                 |options               |
                                   |...                   |
                                   +----------------------+
```

But I think the better decision could be if I create "features" table for each device. Is it possible to address table by id? Is it good decision to have names of tables in "device" table under "dName" and to have huge quantity of "features" tables?

Comment: what is your use-case? For example, what types of queries might you be writing where it would make sense to have a separate "features" table per-device? `VIEW`s may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Where does this idea comes from ? What would even be the problem using your first idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I think the better decision could be if I create "features" table for each device.

This would be contrary to the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Orthogonal_Design).

**Don't do it**.  At least not without *very* good reason.  Your first proposal of a single `features` table for all devices is by far the better solution.

Comment: Can you explain why? Sorry, missed link to "Principle of Orthogonal Design".

Comment: @user2613814: Violating this principle can give rise to ambiguous, potentially inconsistent data and can lead to redundancy and complexity in your data manipulation code.